# How to send this blob field to the server?

Tags: javascript, audio, blob, audio-recording

I am using the audiojs recorder library from matt diamond and it creates a blob which references/points to a local memory address.  This is returned in the html5 audio player and can play.  It looks something like this:  blob:https%3A//www.voicebitz.com/cd83d7e9-dc49-4b1e-9b9a-c45260af5756

My question is how to use this information and send it to the server to store the audio on the server using java script?

I tried to send it as is, but the blob is not recognized.  This is what I tried to do with no luck.

```
function test_convert(){
  var blob = $("#playas_curr_0").find("audio").attr('src');
  console.log("the blob " +  blob + " " + blob.size + " " + blob.type); //returns the string "blob:https%3A//..." for blob and undefined for size and type
  var whatsthis = Object.prototype.toString(blob);    
  console.log(whatsthis);  //returns Object

  var arrayBuffer;
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  
  fileReader.onload = function(){
    var convertthis = fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);  //errors out is not recognized as a blob
    }
}
```

NOTE:  Question was changed after I got more clarification from commenter.
Original text follows.
I realize it is local, but I want to take that blob and then upload it to the server.  I know there are other questions/answers out here about saving to the server and even this library will be able to do it, but I want to separate this process so that it does not do it all in one go.

For example, the flow I want to make is: record local on the recorder start stop actions, I am happy with my recording and so I want to save it, I push a Save button and it grabs this "blob" and then does the save to the server.

Hope the question makes sense and someone can help.

Comment: that looks like a url. e.g. your player fetches whatever's at the specified address, `http://www.voicecity/...` and whatever's returned from there is probably the actual audio data.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, so it is referencing some local storage address.  Any ideas how to work with that? When I try to get the type of the object via prototype.toString it just gives me [object Object] so I don't really know what I can do with that.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I just POST the blob in the data field using ajax.

```
function uploadAudio(mp3Data){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var fd = new FormData();
        var mp3Name = encodeURIComponent('audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.mp3');
        console.log("mp3name = " + mp3Name);
        fd.append('fname', mp3Name);
        fd.append('data', event.target.result);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/sessions/'+localStorage.sessionID+'/audio',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        });
    };      
    reader.readAsDataURL(mp3Data);
}
```

To call:

```
uploadAudio(blob)
```

Comment: I am not sure what is different about what you are doing from the audiojs library, but anyway this is not working.  My main challenge is figuring out how to retrieve the "data" that is apparently stored at that location in the data url.  If you can shed some light on that that would be great.  Thanks for your help.